# .Net Core - Multi Tenant Controller Overrides

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, multi-tenant, saas

I am looking to add multi-tenancy to an .net core MVC application i am developing.

My aim is to have a core project which contains the base features, including controllers, views, assets etc.

Then I would like to have a separate project per tenant which can override the defaults from the core project. At the moment i am trying to tackle the task of overriding controllers, not just at the controller level but the ability to override individual actions within a controller.

What are should i be looking to to do this, I was thinking about the IControllerFactory but not sure if this is the correct place in .net core?

I'm assuming there may be a away to achieve this with IoC but need pointing in the right direction.

Anyone have any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1):

This is the way I designed it on my current project, my requirement is slightly different to yours in that its multi-tenated but a tenant can operate in mutiple countries, the functionality is the same per tenant but different per country, the design below will hopefully give you a few ideas to help you on your way.

I treat the controllers as nothing more than a navigation mechanism, keep them thin and light. I have an area per country (in your scenario this could be an area per tenant)

[image]

Each areas controllers simply reference a base controller

[image]

The base controller is very light because we want be able to implement custom logic per country using our DI container. Lets run through the Edit scenario for a permit.

[image]
*Intellisense playing up view shouldnt be red :)*

Edit permit calls _editPermitManager which is of type IEditPermitManager injected into our controller. I have two implementations of this in the system one for New Zealand because its a special case and one all other countries use (but you could easily have an implementation per country).

[image]

[image]

I manage this injection with ninject
[image]

The flow is user navigates to /blah/NewZealand/Permit/Edit/4 clicks submit this is directed to Permit controller in NewZealand therefore ninjects injects the New Zealand edit manager and this is invoked on the edit flow, I also inject in a INavigationService (_navigationService.Route) enabling me to potentially direct to different views on a per country basis.

Hopefully that gives you a starting point.